# Emgu AdaptiveThreshold

Tags: opencv

I am programming some code in visual basic language, using Emgu CV library.
I need to know how to use function AdaptiveThreshold please

```
Dim inputImage As Emgu.CV.InputArray
Dim outputImage As Emgu.CV.IOutputArray
Dim maxValue As Double = 225
Dim adaptiveType As CvEnum.AdaptveThresholdType
Dim block_size As Integer = 7
Dim parameter As Double = 3

AdaptiveThreshold(inputImage, outputImage, maxValue, adaptiveType, block_size, parameter)
```

this way I get the error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How can I initialize outputImage variable??

IF I use "New" i get the error:
"New cannot be used on an interface"

Can someone help m please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IOutputArray is an interface. You have to use Image object.

```
Dim outputImage As Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>
```